# How to add Organisation Tag Field in Podio?

Tags: podio

Hi I am trying to add Organisation tag with following code:

```
PodioAPI.Models.Item addItem = new PodioAPI.Models.Item();
var organisationTag = addItem.Field<XXXXXXXX>("organisation");
```

I am not sure, which type of field I have to put in place of `XXXX`. For email it is `EmailItemField` and for Phone it is `PhoneItemField`.

Here I am not sure about the organisation field.

Answer (score 0):

That should be `TagItemField` but I'm not sure if it's supported in C# client.

Comment: No, Tag Item Field is not supported in PodioAPI or using PodioAPI.Utils.ItemFields. Could you please let me know is there any other way?

Comment: TagItem is supported in PodioAPI but not supported in C# client.